# Automata and prolog

Tags: prolog, finite-automata

I've been trying to make a non-deterministic finite automata in PROLOG, here is my code:

```
state(1).
state(2).
state(3).

initial_state(1).
final_state(3).

alphabet(a).
alphabet(b).

delta(1, b, 2).
delta(2, a, 2).
delta(2, a, 3).
delta(3, b, 2).

accept([X|[]], Q) :- 
    alphabet(X),
    delta(Q, X, Q1),
    final_state(Q1).
accept([X|XS], Q) :- 
    alphabet(X),
    delta(Q, X, Q1),
    accept(XS, Q1).
```

Where accept is a function that given a string and a state, it will tell us if it's accepted by the automata.
The problem is that when I try to see if the string baba ([b,a,b,a]) is accepted by the automata (accept([b,a,b,a],1)) I get true, which is not right.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/l-flat/lflat You can run it with most Prolog systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you think it should fail?
The solution sequence is

```
delta(1, b, 2)
delta(2, a, 3)
delta(2, a, 2)
delta(2, a, 3)
```

My personal "best practice" is to collect the proof

```
accept([X|[]], Q,[delta(Q, X, Q1)]) :- 
    alphabet(X),
    delta(Q, X, Q1),
    print(delta(Q, X, Q1)),nl,
    final_state(Q1).
accept([X|XS], Q,[delta(Q, X, Q1)|Rest]) :- 
    alphabet(X),
    delta(Q, X, Q1),
    print(delta(Q,X,Q1)),nl,
    accept(XS, Q1,Rest).
accept(String,State):-accept(String,State,_).
```

this shows you that the program can be proofed with the above sequence

```
?- accept([b,a,b,a],1, Proof).
Proof = [delta(1, b, 2), delta(2, a, 3), delta(3, b, 2), delta(2, a, 3)]
```

Comment: I assume you have a mistake in the numbering of your states in the transitions but the proof sequence is as I described

Comment: Thanks, I'll use your personal best practice in the future. :p

Comment: @Mystery: out of curiosity is my assumption with the transitions right? if so what was the intented definition?